# Liferay Taglib import not working in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, import, liferay, taglib

I'm having trouble importing the liferay taglibs in one of my JSP pages, no idea what I'm doing wrong. I did the exact same thing in previous projects, but now for some reason it's not working.

My code to import:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://liferay.com/tld.ui" prefix="liferay-ui" %>
```

The syntax error I'm getting:

```
The absolute uri: http://liferay.com/tld.ui cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application
```

I tried to google this problem quite extensively, but to no avail. The horrible documentation (or lack thereof) for liferay is also not a big help at all.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: I get a 404 on the URL, perhaps they have decomissioned?

Comment: You shouldn't need to add it to your Web.xml for Liferay. But you do need the jstl.jar on your WEB-INF/lib directory as Ramesh says below.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The taglib URI  gets resolved from the following places(in the order):

1. If the container is Java EE platform compliant, the tag libraries that are part of the Java EE platform. This currently includes `JSTL and JSF Tag Library` libraries.
2. `Taglib Map in web.xml`, the web.xml can include an explicit map of URI's and TLD's respource paths.
3. `TLDs in JAR files in WEB-INF/lib` and `TLDs under WEB-INF`
4. `TLD's supported by Container`

In you case, check the following cases:
1) If jar file realted to liferay exists in WEB-INF/lib containing a TLD in `jar/META-INF` which will be defined with `http://liferay.com/tld.ui` URI.
2) If there is not jar file and the `liferay-ui.tld` exists outside the jar file, add the URI mapping entrey in your web.xml like below:

```
<taglib>
    <taglib-uri>http://liferay.com/tld/ui</taglib-uri>
    <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/tld/liferay-ui.tld</taglib-location>
</taglib>
```

Comment: In my experience Number 1 is necessary, 2 is not.

Comment: @Jonny Have updated the answer, can you please let me know if you have some comments.

Comment: Nope, it's not working. The taglib tags are defined in the web.xml document. And the jars and tld are in the right place. I honestly don't know what else to do. Re-create the project and see if it works?

Comment: @DeanGrobler Can you please check if the tld file exists at the /WEB-INF/tld/ location

Answer (score 2):

it is not

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://liferay.com/tld.ui" prefix="liferay-ui" %>
```

it should be

```
<%@ taglib prefix="liferay-ui" uri="http://liferay.com/tld/ui" %>
```

notice that "tld.ui" must be "tld/ui".

liferay-ui.tld comes from util-taglib.jar that liferay adds to your WEB-INF/lib during hot deploy.

No entries to your web.xml are needed.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to include taglib declaration in your web.xml.

```
    <taglib>
        <taglib-uri>http://liferay.com/tld/ui</taglib-uri>
        <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/tld/liferay-ui.tld</taglib-location>
    </taglib>
```